# React.children.only expected to receive a single react element child Navigator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I tried too many topic helps but that doesn't help me to fix this error, maybe cuz i'm newbie to react-native.

here is the code which gives error.

```
render() {
  return (

  <Provider store={store}>

    <Navigator
      initialRoute={{ name: 'Wake' }}
      configureScene={(route, routeStack) => Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottom}
      renderScene={RouteMapper}
    />

    <Tabs />



  </Provider>


 );
}
```

"React.children.only expected to receive a single react element child" i get this error when i run it. please help.
iam aware that there are lot of other topics posted similar but none gives a proper solution to my problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The react-redux `<Provider />` component expects its child prop to be a single ReactElement, the root component of your application. That is probably where this error is coming from.

> **Props**
>
> - store (Redux Store): The single Redux store in your application.
> - children (ReactElement) The root of your component hierarchy.
>
> **Example**
>
> ```
> ReactDOM.render(
>   <Provider store={store}>
>     <div>
>         <MyRootComponent/>
>         <OtherComponent1/>
>         <OtherComponent2/>
>         // {...} as longer you let the component inside one global component 
>         // - here the divs - React considers you have only one child. That it. 
>     </div>
>   </Provider>,
>   rootEl
> );
> ```

Source: https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#provider-store

Comment: could you give me example with my code? i don't understand that

Comment: Try creating a new component that wraps your Navigator and Tabs components. Then nest that inside of Provider.

Comment: Sorry iam a newbie, can you please give me example?

Answer (score 4):

Might be late to the post, but you could wrap `React.Fragment` around your Navigator and Tab to get around that error. https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

```
render() {
  return (

  <Provider store={store}>
    <React.Fragment>
       <Navigator
         initialRoute={{ name: 'Wake' }}
         configureScene={(route, routeStack) => Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottom}
         renderScene={RouteMapper}
       />

       <Tabs />
    </React.Fragment>


  </Provider>


 );
}
```

Comment: Nice! Also transferable to React Native.

Answer (score 3):

The above answers did not give you a code example, I will add some code that applies to your situation:

```
const Root = () => {
  return (
   <div>
    <Navigator
      initialRoute={{ name: 'Wake' }}
      configureScene={(route, routeStack) => Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottom}
      renderScene={RouteMapper}
    />

    <Tabs />
   </div>
 )   
}


render() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Root />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

You basically need to wrap up your Nav and Tabs components inside a Root component to render it within the Provider component, as said in other answers.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag

Comment: Yes passing Root as a function of component in Provider, it works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The Provider component from redux expects to have only one child. You're passing it two children, Navigator and Tabs. Wrap everything inside Provider in a single component.

Comment: Example?
Well i tried like this 

{<Navigator
      ......
    />, <Tabs />}

But only the <Tabs> are showing up in the app.