# Render functions won't work for sidebar

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm following https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sidebar to implement a sidebar.  [I'm getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MULC1.png) upon refreshing my `iOS` simulator.  I followed the directions as is, but in my `WebStorm IDE` it's saying `Unresolved function or method renderLeftSideBar()` and `Unresolved function or method renderLeftSideBar()`.

Here's the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Application from './pages/Application';
import store from './redux';
import api from './utilities/api';
import SideBar from 'react-native-sidebar';

export default class DApp extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            isLoading: true
        }
        console.log("something");
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        api.getData().then((res) => {
            this.setState({
                data: res.data
            })
        });
    }

    renderLeftSideBar() {
    return(
        <Text>Someting here for left side bar!</Text>
    );
}

renderRightSideBar() {
    return(
        <Text>Someting here for right side bar!</Text>
    );
}

renderContent() {
    return(
        <Text>The content!</Text>
    );
}      

    render() {
        if(this.state.isLoading) {
            console.log("The data is: " + this.state.data);
        } else {
            console.log("Else got executed");
        }

        return (

            <Provider store={store}>
                <SideBar>
                    leftSideBar = {this.renderLeftSideBar()}
                    rightSideBar = {this.renderRightSideBar()}
                    style = {{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'black'}}>{this.renderContent()}
                </SideBar>
              <Application />
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('DApp', () => DApp);
```

Comment: define your `renderLeftSideBar`, `renderRightSideBar` and `renderContent` functions

Comment: to be clear about things read about `this` keyword in javascript and how does this behave while using the `class` keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class DApp doesn't have a function `renderLeftSideBar()`; this is why your function is `unresolved`.

To fix this, you need to create a function `renderLeftSideBar()` that returns the content for the left side bar. Reading the documentation you linked shows that leftSideBar is of type Component.

> leftSidebar: Compontent

Typically, I would define the function above `render()`.

```
renderLeftSideBar() {
    return <div>
        (content goes here)
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Ok, I defined all of them (I changed up my code in the original post) but now it's giving me an error that says `React,children only expected to recieve a single React element child`.

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43300897/react-children-only-expected-to-receive-a-single-react-element-child-navigator

Comment: Perhaps its because you have both SideBar and Application nested inside <Provider>.

Comment: Yeah I had just came across that page just a second ago.  Thanks a lot!