# Uncaught Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, antd

I am trying to create a web table using antd library  but i am getting into an error

> "react.development.js:1251 Uncaught Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child".I am totally stuck and not able to find a solution.Can someone help?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Table, Divider, Tag } from 'antd';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { getOrdersByUser } from '../../../../store/profile/action';

class TableInvoices extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(getOrdersByUser('buyer1@gmail.com'));
    }

    render() {
        

        // const tableData = [
        //     {
        //         id: '1',
        //         invoice_id: '500884010',
        //         product_title: 'Marshall Kilburn Portable Wireless Speaker',
        //         invoice_date: '20-1-2020',
        //         cost: '42.99',
        //         status: 'Successful delivery',
        //     },
        //     {
        //         id: '2',
        //         invoice_id: '593347935',
        //         product_title: 'Herschel Leather Duffle Bag In Brown Color',
        //         invoice_date: '20-1-2020',
        //         cost: '199.99',
        //         status: 'Cancel',
        //     },
        // ];
        let tableData = [];
        const { userOrderHistory } = this.props;
        if (
            typeof userOrderHistory != 'undefined' &&
            userOrderHistory.length > 0
        ) {
            tableData = this.props.userOrderHistory.map((row) => ({
                id: row.id,
                invoiceID: row.invoice_id,
                productTitle: row.product_title,
                invoiceDate: row.invoice_date,
                cost: row.cost,
                status: row.status,
            }));
        }
        const tableColumn = [
            {
                title: 'Id',
                dataIndex: 'invoiceID',
                rowKey: 'invoiceID',
                key: 'invoiceID',
                width: '120px',
                render: (text, record) => (
                    <Link href="/account/invoice-detail">
                        {record.invoiceID}
                    </Link>
                ),
            },
            {
                title: 'Title',
                dataIndex: 'productTitle',
                rowKey: 'productTitle',
                key: 'productTitle',
            },
            {
                title: 'Date',
                rowKey: 'invoiceDate',
                dataIndex: 'invoiceDate',
                key: 'invoiceDate',
                width: '120px',
            },
            {
                title: 'Amount',
                rowKey: 'cost',
                dataIndex: 'cost',
                key: 'cost',
                render: (text, record) => (
                    <span className="text-right">${record.cost}</span>
                ),
            },
            {
                title: 'Status',
                key: 'status',
                dataIndex: 'status',
                rowKey: 'status',
                width: '150px',
                render: (text, record) => (
                    <span className="text-right">{record.status}</span>
                ),
            },
        ];
        console.log('tableColumn');
        return (
            <Table
                columns={tableColumn}
                dataSource={tableData}
                rowKey={(record) => record.id}
            />
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return state.profile;
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TableInvoices);
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `connect` and the Redux `Provider` expect single child components, so one thing to check is: from what I'm seeing on the the antd docs, the Table Component can return multiple children, **try wrapping your table component in a Fragment.**

Otherwise, are you sure it's coming from this file?
Maybe the problem comes from the Redux Provider, in which case:
[React.children.only expected to receive a single react element child Navigator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43300897/react-children-only-expected-to-receive-a-single-react-element-child-navigator) will help

Also, just in case, even though that would be very surprising to me, have you tried removing the white space in between your parentheses and the actual component you return? Maybe there is a no-break space?

```
return <Table
  columns={tableColumn}
  dataSource={tableData}
  rowKey={(record) => record.id}
/>
```

Comment: Code works fine if {tableData} is hardcoded inside the react component...When i trying read it from API it throws error...i have compared output from API with hardcoded table data...it's exactly the same.

Comment: How unfortunate, hard to tell without being able to inspect things, maybe you can add a jsfiddle for us to explore the roots of the problem?